# Projecting Lat Lng onto image coordinate system (reverse georeferencing?)

Tags: qgis, leaflet, georeferencing

We have multiple illustrated maps. They are based on real places but some features are slightly distorted or exaggerated. They are also often slightly rotated.

We've already created several prototypes by georeferencing the illustrated maps in QGIS, exporting XYZ tiles as a directory and displaying them with Leaflet.

This works okay. However, it has the undesirable side effects of distorting and rotating the original illustrated map.

My ideal goal would be to render a Leaflet map in the image's original coordinate system. The Leaflet docs on [Non-geographical maps](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html) seem interesting for doing this.

However, the difference is that these *are* maps that represent real-world coordinates (as opposed to video-game coordinates or something).

I also want to bring in other data with real-world lat/lng coordinates and display it on the illustrated map. Some of this data would be created by hand and could be created based on the image's coordinate system. However some of it would come from phone GPS sources (e.g. the user's current location).

The thing I'm looking for is a way to project lat/lng coords back into the image's coordinate system. This kind of feels like the opposite of georeferencing to me.

Before starting to use Leaflet or QGIS, we'd created a prototype that did pretty much this already. It took a bunch of control points, created a Triangulated Irregular Network (using [turf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/tin)) then looked up the triangle you were already in and calculated the new position based on your position in the current triangle. Although that worked, it was hacky and slow and was created before we'd even heard the term "georeferencing".

Does something like this already exist? Can anyone point me towards any examples that do this kind of projection using Leaflet?

Also, while some of the maps are distorted in complex ways, most of them could be georeferenced with only the corners if that makes it simpler.

Comment: I guess some screenshots of input, current output and desired output would help.

Comment: I think you're just looking for proj4leaflet.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Interesting, I'd noticed proj4 in random searches before but it seemed very complex. Is there a way to create a proj4 string from control points?

Comment: No, you have a different problem: knowing the projection of your maps. Do research "georectification", read e.g. https://mapwarper.net/